# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () nodes, react, mysql

Tags: reactjs, node.js

my English is not so good. using a node js and react js with mysql. signup page work properly but login page getting a error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

1. server.js(node.js)

   ```
   const express = require("express");
   const app = express();
   const session = require('express-session');
   const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   const cors = require("cors");
   app.use(express.json());
   app.use(cors());
   const { sequelize } = require('./db'); // Import Sequelize instance

   sequelize.authenticate()
   .then(() => {
     console.log('Database connection has been established successfully.');
   })
   .catch((error) => {
     console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
   });

   app.use(express.static('public'));
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
   app.use(session({
     secret: 'secret-key',
     resave: false,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 }
   }));


   const signup = require("./routes/signup");
   app.use("/auth",signup);

   const login = require("./routes/login");
   app.use("/auth", login);


   const dashboard = require("./routes/dashboard");
   app.use("/auth",dashboard)


   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
   app.listen(PORT, () => {
     console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
   });
   ```
2. db.js(node.js)

   ```
   const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
   const config = require('./config/config.json');
   const userTable = require('./models/userTable');

   const dbConfig = config.development;

   const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.database, dbConfig.username, dbConfig.password, {
     host: dbConfig.host,
     dialect: dbConfig.dialect
   });
   const User = userTable(sequelize, DataTypes);


   module.exports = {
     sequelize,
     User,
   };
   ```
3. login.js (node.js)

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const router = express.Router();
   const path = require('path');
   const {User} = require('../db');
   const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')


   const { naverClientId, appleClientId, kakaoClientId } = require('../config/clientID.json');
   const { Result } = require('express-validator');


   router.get('/naver-login', (req, res) => {
     // Redirect to Naver for login
     res.redirect(`https://nid.naver.com/oauth2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${naverClientId}&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&state=YOUR_STATE`);
   });

   router.get('/apple-login', (req, res) => {
     // Redirect to Apple for login
     res.redirect(`https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?client_id=${appleClientId}&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code&scope=name%20email`);
   });

   router.get('/kakao-login', (req, res) => {
     // Redirect to Kakao Talk for login
     res.redirect(`https://kauth.kakao.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=${kakaoClientId}&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code`);
   });

   router.post("/login", async (req,res) => {
     const {email, password} = req.body;
     try {
       const user = User.findOne({where: {email}});
       if(!user) {
         return res.status(401).json ({ message: "invalid email or password"});
       }

       const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

       if(isPasswordValid) {
         req.session.user = user; 
         return (
           // res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful', user })
           res.redirect("/auth/dashboard")
         )
       } else {
         return (
           res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid email or password' })
         )
       }
     } catch (error) {
       console.error('Error during login:', error);
       res.status(500).send('An error occurred');
     }
     });


   module.exports = router;
   ```
4. login.jsx(react.js)

   ```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
   import axios from 'axios'; 
   import "../CSS/login.css";

   function LoginPage() {
     const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
     const [password,setPassword] = useState('');


     const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();

       try {
         const response = await axios('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', { email,password });
         if (response.status === 200){
           const data = response.data;

           console.log(data);
           window.location.href = 'auth/dashboard';

         }else {
           console.error("login failed");
         }
       }
       catch (error) {
         console.error('error: ', error);
       }
     }


     return (
       <div>
         <header>
           <div className="login-form">
             <form action="/auth/login" method="POST">
               {/* Username Input */}
               <label htmlFor="email">이메일</label>
               <input
                 type="email"
                 id="email"
                 name="email"
                 required
                 value={email}
                 onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
               />
               {/* Password Input */}
               <label htmlFor="password">비밀번호</label>
               <input
                 type="password"
                 id="password"
                 name="password"
                 required
                 value={password}
                 onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
               />

               {/* Email Login Button */}
               <button type="submit">이메일 로그인</button>

               {/* Forget Password and Sign-Up Links */}
               <div className="forgetPassword">
                 <Link to="/auth/forgetpassword" id="forgot-password-link">비밀번호 찾기?</Link>
                 <Link to="/auth/signup" id="sign-up-link">회원가입</Link>
               </div>

               {/* Social Media Login Buttons */}
               <div className="authorityLogin">
                 <div className="naverLogin">
                   <button type="button" id="naver-login">
                     <Link to="/naver-login"><img src="/Photo/naverLogin.png" alt="naver login" /></Link>

                   </button>
                 </div>

                 <div className="appleLogin">
                   <button type="button" id="apple-login">
                     <Link to="/apple-login"><i className="fab fa-apple"></i></Link>Apple로 로그인
                   </button>
                 </div>

                 <div className="kakaoLogin">
                   <button type="button" id="kakao-login">
                     <Link to="/kakao-login"><img src="/Photo/kakaoLogin.png" alt="kakao login" /></Link>
                   </button>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </form>
           </div>
         </header>
       </div>
     );
   }

   export default LoginPage;
   ```

my signup page work properly but my login doesn't work

my login.jsx(login.js) keep getting a (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ())

Comment: Http error 404 means the URL you requested is not found on your server. Fix the url.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the axios part in login.jsx with this one

```
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/auth/login', { email, password });
```

If you are using axios() instead of axios.post(), you should do it like this

```
const config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/auth/login',
  data: { email,password },
};
axios(config);
```